# i need to fix div tags using beautifulsoup in python

Tags: javascript, python, html, jquery, css

I am using python 2.7 and beautifulsoup==4.9.3 in the docker file.
when I am importing bs4 module getting error.

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

error:

Getting no module named bs4

but it is successfully installing in docker container.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There might be so many causes for the issue, try these

- Python Environment:

Ensure that the Python environment where you installed it is the same one where you're trying to run your script. Sometimes, there might be multiple Python installations or virtual environments, and the package might be installed in one but not the other.

- Explicitly Check Installation:

After starting your Docker container, run this to check if beautifulsoup4 is indeed installed:

```
pip2 list | grep beautifulsoup4
```

- Correct Python Path:

  Ensure that the PYTHONPATH environment variable includes the location    where the bs4 module is installed. You can print the
  sys.path within    your Python script to see the directories Python
  is checking for    modules:

import sys

print(sys.path)